# How can I walk in a scene using aframe.js?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, aframe

I'm working in a 3D project and I need to walk inside but I cannot find the method or function using "universal controls"

I got this taked for an example:

```
 <a-entity position="1.75 0 1.2" rotation="0 28 0">
    <a-camera near="0.1" user-height="0"></a-camera>
  </a-entity>
```

The problem is, I cannot walk whit that code but the entities (the black things on the project) can move and I don't want it. I want to move around the scene, you can see my project online here: http://www.losmarcs.com/VR/

Comment: I think you'll need to say more about what you're using. Do you mean physically walking, like with a Vive? Or WASD/arrow keys? If you're using [aframe-extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras), there should be a `universal-controls` component on your camera. If just vanilla A-Frame, you need a [wasd-controls](https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/wasd-controls.html) or `look-controls` component on the camera.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I mean WASD/arrow with the keyboard

Comment: Great! Just wrote it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use WASD/arrow navigation in A-Frame, the default component to use is [`wasd-controls`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/wasd-controls.html). This component should be added to the same element as the `camera` component. For roomscale walking (e.g. Vive) you also need the `look-controls` component.

If you're also using [aframe-extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras), you would instead use the `universal-controls` component on the camera element.